# A pair of unbiased dice are rolled together till a sum of either 5 or 7 is obtained, find the probability that 5 comes before 7

Tags: probability

Problem :

> A pair of unaiased dice are rolled together till a sum of either 5 or 7 is obtained, find the probability that 5 comes before 7.

My approach :

Probability P(A) of getting 5 as sum on two dice is

$$P(A) = \frac{4}{36} = \frac{1}{9}$$

Let B the event that a sum of 7 occurs and C the event that neither a sum of 5 nor a sum of 7 occurs. We have :

$$P(B)= \frac{6}{36} = \frac{1}{6}$$

$$P(C) = \frac{26}{36} = \frac{13}{18}$$

Please suggest how to proceed further.

Comment: Not interested in the answer below?

Answer (score 17):

The number of results of a pair of dice which sum to `5` is $4$. The number of results of a pair of dice which sum to `7` is $6$. Thus, if the dice are unbiased, they will produce the sum `5` before the sum `7` with probability $\frac4{4+6}=\frac25$.

More generally, for two disjoint events `A` and `B` with probabilities $a$ and $b$ respectively, to observe `A` before `B` means either that the first try yields `A` (this happens with probability $a$), or that the first try yields neither `A` nor `B` (this happens with probability $1-a-b$) and that the following tries produce `A` before `B`.

This one-step reasoning indicates that the probability $p$ to observe `A` before `B` solves the equation $p=a\cdot1+b\cdot0+(1-a-b)\cdot p$, thus, $p=\frac{a}{a+b}$.

Answer (score 3):

You are interested that the game will end where you first get sum of $5$, and that it will happen before the first "sum of $7$". Hence, by noting that the first event has $4$ elementary outcomes while the second has $6$, and by using the law of total probability, you get 
\begin{align}
P(\text{ 5 before 7}) &=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(\text{ sum of $5$}|\text{$n-1$ times neither $5$ or $7$} )P(\text{$n-1$ times neither $5$ or $7$} )\\
&=\frac{4}{36} \frac{26^0}{36^0} + \frac{4}{36} \frac{26^1}{36^1}+\cdots+ \frac{4}{36} \frac{26^{n-1}}{36^{n-1}}\\
&= 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{26}{36}\right)^{n-1}\frac{4}{36}\\
& = \frac{1}{9}\frac{1}{1-13/18}\\
& = \frac{2}{5} .
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please explain more how you have used law of total probability

Comment: I've edited the answer.